# How to write if/else in java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

How do I convert this below if/else statement to java stream pipeline?

I have an Optional<> and if That is present then I am making a database call which returns a list and I want to stream over that list and if certain condition is met I want to perform an operation and if not I want to perform some other operation

```
if(returnOptional().isPresent) {
    List<Object> list = db.findAllById(id);
    if(list.stream().anyMatch(x -> /*predicate*/)){
        //perform function
    } else {
        //perform function
    }
}
```

Partial Solution :

```
      returnOptional()
      .map(obj -> {
        List<Object> list = db.call();
        return list.stream()
          .filter(/*Predicate*/)
          .findAny().map(object -> /*function*/)
          .orElse(null);
    }).orElseGet(() -> /*function*/);
```

Comment: You should clarify, what kind of function you want to execute here. Is it some operation on the found x, or something to be performed on an otherwise not related object?

Comment: So you kind of want to branch the stream into two and perform different logic on each of the two branches?

Comment: @Philipp yes, you got that right

Comment: Instead of `anyMatch(predicate)`  you could try `filter(predicate).findAny().isPresentOrElse(/*consumer for true*/, /*runnable for false*/)`.

Comment: @Philipp that's something different

Comment: @Thomas Thanks thomas but this function is not in java8 which is the one I am using

Comment: How is it different?

Comment: Well `.map(/*...*/).orElseGet(/*...*/)` should work as well

Comment: @Philipp I have an ```Optional<>``` and if That is present then I am making a database call which returns a list and I want to stream over that list and if certain condition is met I want to perform an operation and if not I want to perform some other operation

Comment: And which part of that would not be possible with the answers to the question I linked to?

Comment: @Philipp Now I got you phillip. Thanks

Comment: As of Java 12 you can use `Collectors.teeing()` to create two streams and process each one separately.

Comment: Why is this operation dependent on the presence of `returnOptional()` when it never uses its value? Besides that, there’s no sense in converting the second if/else statement to java stream pipeline. It’s a single condition and the canonical syntax for doing something when the condition is fulfilled and something else when not is an if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if(returnOptional().isPresent) {
List<Object> list = db.findAllById(id);

list.stream().map(object -> {
    if(/*predicate logic*/) {
        // perform function if predicate logic true
    }
    else {
        // perform function if predicate logic false
    }
    return object;
  });
}
```

but as philip mentioned technically you cannot split a stream into two streams and collect.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Optional.ofNullable(list).ifPresent( y -> {
                    if (y.stream().anyMatch(x -> /*predicate*/)) {
                        System.out.println("a");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("b");
                    }
                });
```